# Android browser can not download image from my nginx server

Tags: android, nginx

I have a **nginx server(1.2.4)**, it provides some images to download. However, I did not put these file in public folder as I want to do some authentication or something else.

I use `X-Accel-Redirect` feature of `nginx` for these static files. Now I can download there images from desktop browser, so I think I have configure the nginx right.

However, when I use android device, I can not download those files. Android always show me **"download unsuccessfully"** with a "untitled name". I change Content-Disposition to "inline", then I can see the image in browser, so I think the data has been sent to device.

I do not know why android device can not download successfully even the data has been sent.

Another things is if I just put the image files in "public" folder, let android device directly download there, android device will work correctly, it can download images.

So, if I use nginx `X-Accel-Redirect` feature to provice images, android can not download even data has been sent,
if I just put them in public folder, android browser can download.

please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I've read somewhere that this is because Android has a "bug" that requires metadata for any downloaded file. So we should configure nginx to give the metadata depending on the type of file (pdf, xls, and so on, except web as html/php and so on)